# Skobbler does not render map on iOS 10 + SKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, skmaps

I am trying to use Skobbler to render an offline map.
I don't have any problems on iOS9, I can display the map, annotations... but on iOS10, I can only display annotations, no map !
The app doesn't crash, it downloads the data OK,...

Can you help me find a solution ? 
I already tried to integrate my project into demo project and it's the same result.

[image]

Comment: On the device running iOS 10 is the vanilla demo-project running correctly ?

Comment: I am facing problem. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I think it is a memory problem, sometimes if you restart the device, the map appears. We chose to import the data into the project and do not use the download feature to solve this issue.